# How to anonymously and privately purchase Bitcoin through Tor?

Tags: privacy, buy-bitcoins, tor

How can Bitcoin be anonymously purchased through Tor in a secure and private fashion?

My question is related to:

- [How can I setup Bitcoin to be anonymous with Tor?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/70069/10651)
- [Personal information and bitcoin purchasing](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74803/10651)

but more focused on *anonymous* and *private* purchasing transactions.

Comment: This question has been voted as off-topic citing the market value close reason. I've voted to leave open, as this is not asking about a service provider, but about ways to address a specific need.

Comment: what is the market value close option?  And, yes, not asking about a specific service provider.

Comment: I was referring to the off-topic close reason "Questions on current or future market values, energy costs or service provider availability are off-topic as the answers are changing too frequently to be useful to others.". In my opinion, it doesn't apply here. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, anonimity and privacy are two different things. Bitcoin is designed to be pseudonimous - which is close to anonimity, but instead of being completely anonimous, you're linked to your bitcoin address, or pseudonym.
You cannot make a private transaction on the Bitcoin network, but you can try to be as anonymous as possible.

It is possible to run Bitcoin Core as a Tor hidden service, and connect to such services.
The first step is running Bitcoin Core behind a Tor proxy. This will already anonymize all outgoing connections, but more is possible.

More instructions at github:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/tor.md

Answer (score 1):

For purchasing BTC in a private way, you should buy OTC (not from centralized exchanges). One possible way is Bitcoin ATMs, another option is using HodlHodl.com (works with Tor Browser) or Bisq (software you install on your computer), both of which just connect buyers and sellers and then you can do the trade using various payment methods, including meeting in person and paying with cash.